# How to use multiple frame (C-x 5 2) within only one (system's) window in GUI Emacs?

Tags: frames, gui-emacs

In console version of Emacs (`emacs -nw`), I can create `frame` with `C-x 5 2` and use `C-x 5 o` to switch between them. This concept is just like "workspace" in Linux desktop, or "Mission Constrol" in macOS.

However, when I use `C-x 5 2` under GUI Emacs, Emacs create a new (OS's window, not the `window` in Emacs) window. I don't like it.

How to make frame's behavior in GUI the same as in console?

Comment: You cannot make GUI Emacs behave like terminal Emacs in so far as frames are concerned.  There are alternatives to keep everything in just one GUI frame like `tabbar` and `elscreen`, but if you like terminal, then just stick with that.  I personally stick with the GUI version on OSX and just line up my frames one on top of the other so that it gives the appearance of just one frame -- Emacs lets us control the exact pixel size and location of frames, so lining them up (one on top of the other) is a breeze.  I even have a function to maximize all, and shrink all frames in one fell swoop.